# Django PostgreSQL - Indexes on JsonField vs. custom fields

Tags: django, postgresql

I am working on a booking system on Django with the following context:

- Users can create Items for others to book
- They can further specify the 'available time' per weekday (mon-sun), i.e. opening_time & closing_time. We can also expect that: A. most users adopt the same 'default' values across 7 weekdays (i.e. override when necessary), and B. most users adopt the same default values, say 8am-10pm.
- A search on Items by its availability, e.g. "Monday 3-4pm", will be expected and of considerably high traffic, so query performance is a must.

---

I have a few options in mind but cannot decide which is better:

**Option A: Default values + JsonField + index**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField   

class Item(models.Model):
    opening_time = models.TimeField()
    closing_time = models.TimeField()
    override = JsonField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(models.F("override__sun_open"), name="override__sun_open"),
            models.Index(models.F("override__sun_close"), name="override__sun_close"),
            ...
        ]
```

The Json will 'override' if necessary - might look something like `{'sun_open': 07:00, 'sun_close': 23:00}`. The filter() will be more complicated but can save on storage (given most users will use the defaults).

**Option B: JsonField + index**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    available = JsonField()
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(models.F("available__sun_open"), name="available__sun_open"),
            models.Index(models.F("available__sun_close"), name="available__sun_close"),
            ...
        ]
```

The query will be easy but it could be 'wasteful' storage given most opening and closing times are same.

**Option C: All TimeField()**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    sun_open = models.TimeField()
    sun_close = models.TimeField()
    mon_open = models.TimeField()
    ...
```

Similar to B - while we're at it, is there any fundamental difference between option B & C? I'm guessing building indexes on all TimeFields for C would mean doubling the columns? But B comes at the cost(?) of an additional JSON object stored. In other words, what is the tradeoff here given we know definitively there are exactly 14 extra fields.